# Expose node_modules file as an asset

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm writing an app that provides an embed code to users. That embed code has some JavaScript dependencies I got off of npm.

In order to expose it, I first thought would be to simply copy the file from `node_modules` into the `assets` folder. However, this means I must re-copy the file each time the package is updated. (and I just don't like it, you know what I mean ;))

What I'd like to do is specify that file as an asset:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "../node_modules/thepackage/dist/thefile.min.js"
]
```

However, this doesn't work as these three URLs just take me to the Angular app:

- localhost:4200/../node_modules/thepackage/dist/thefile.min.js
- localhost:4200/node_modules/thepackage/dist/thefile.min.js
- localhost:4200/thefile.min.js

Any ideas, or is this something that is not supported (yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4691/commits/6754390f7c4dc44563f3111503c3fcf7fa2128a1) commit, it is now possible.

Use this as your assets:

```
"assets": [
  "./assets",
  {
    "glob": "thefile.min.js",
    "input": "../node_modules/thepackage/dist/",
    "output": "./assets/js/"
  }
]
```